# Is there a Microsoft SQL Profiler equivalent for Oracle

Tags: asp.net, performance, oracle, debugging, sql-server-profiler

99% of my time is in SQL Server land and so I'm not at all familiar with Oracle or its products...Is there a similar application to Microsoft SQL Profiler for use against Oracle databases? I'm helping debug/tune an ASP.Net application that connects to Oracle using ODAC etc

thanks heaps!

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [Oracle: is there a tool to trace queries, like Profiler for sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148648/oracle-is-there-a-tool-to-trace-queries-like-profiler-for-sql-server)

and this:

http://www.oradev.com/create_statistics.jsp

Answer (score 0):

**Explain Plan**

For tuning individual statements you can use "explain plan".  Try a copy of the free Sql Developer, it has a nice GUI interface for this.

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Along with the answers given so far, it is also worth mentioning the  [PL/SQL Profiler](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#sthref2171)

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of profiler tool for Oracle

1. [dbForge Studio for Oracle](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/oracle-sql-profiler.html)
2. [GI Oracle Profiler](http://www.iacosoft.com/home/tools.asp#PROFILER)
3. [Statement Tracer for Oracle](https://download.cnet.com/Statement-Tracer-for-Oracle/3000-10254_4-10138049.html)

Hopefully this is what you are looking for