# Sql vs Oracle - profiler

Tags: oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle: is there a tool to trace queries, like Profiler for sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148648/oracle-is-there-a-tool-to-trace-queries-like-profiler-for-sql-server)

Is there any option in Oracle like Sql profiler to trace the query running in the backend

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148648/oracle-is-there-a-tool-to-trace-queries-like-profiler-for-sql-server

Comment: I've added another answer to the original question.