# How to use Toad to trace SQL

Tags: performance, oracle, profiling, toad

How to use Toad to trace what sql are being executed by my application?  All I want to do is trace what SQL / PL/SQL procedures are being executed by my application and what parameters are being passed?

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can not use TOAD to trace SQL fired by external application, but you can utilize session browser to see what queries are being executed on session basis.There is also oracle utility called tkprof which can be used to profile SQL.Also take a look at this : 
[Oracle: is there a tool to trace queries, like Profiler for sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148648/oracle-is-there-a-tool-to-trace-queries-like-profiler-for-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

In the commercial version of Toad you can use the SQL Tracker which is found in the menu option: Database > Monitor > SQL Tracker. If you don't have that as part of your Toad then they also offer SQL Monitor for free. A blog about it is [here](http://www.toadworld.com/BLOGS/tabid/67/EntryId/402/Introducing-a-New-Free-Utility-Download-SQL-Monitor.aspx).