# How does LINQ pagination statement actually executes against Oracle database?

Tags: database, linq, oracle, entity-framework

Lets consider the following linq statement.

```
var ctx = new MoviesContext();
var movies = ctx.Movies.AsPagination(pagenum??1, 10);
```

I have following **questions** in regards to executing this against **Oracle** in **Entity Framework**

1. For this statement against Oracle, what is the best way for me to see how does the above statement get translated into actual database query?
2. How do I know if records are being filtered at the database level and I am only going to get the 10 records back in the application memory?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a profiler to see what SQL is being executed on the database side of things. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148648/oracle-is-there-a-tool-to-trace-queries-like-profiler-for-sql-server) question talks about some Oracle profilers.