# How to find parameters in Oracle query received from v$sql?

Tags: oracle, parameters, prepared-statement

I use query:

```
 select LAST_LOAD_TIME, ELAPSED_TIME, MODULE, SQL_TEXT elasped from v$sql
 WHERE MODULE='JDBC Thin Client'
 ORDER BY LAST_LOAD_TIME DESC
```

elasped:

```
 delete from tableA where fk in (select pk from tableB where tableB.fk=:1
 and tableB.date between :2 and :3)
```

Is it possible find these parameters 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select s.sql_id, 
       bc.position, 
       bc.value_string, 
       s.last_load_time, 
       bc.last_captured
from v$sql s
  left join v$sql_bind_capture bc 
         on bc.sql_id = s.sql_id 
        and bc.child_number = s.child_number
where s.sql_text like 'delete from tableA where fk%' -- or any other method to identify the SQL statement
order by s.sql_id, bc.position;
```