# Oracle 12c: SQL query hangs forever only occasionally

Tags: oracle

I have a SQL query that fetches roughly 200 columns from multiple tables and normally runs in a matter of minutes.

A Java program kicked off by cron calls the SQL every 4 hours, but occasionally hangs forever(=not fetching any data. Neither updates nor inserts are involved).

Here are some outputs from `V$SESSION`.

**STATUS**: ACTIVE
**ROW_WAIT_OBJ#**: 22392　←not changing
**ROW_WAIT_FILE#**: 6　←not changing
**ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#**: 8896642　←not changing
**ROW_WAIT_ROW#**: 0　←not changing
**LAST_CALL_ET**: 5632　←keeps incresing

★No other heavy SQL queries are running at the same time

What could be the cause of this and what should I look into to solve it?

Comment: Can you use some sort of profiler and see what query is creating this bottleneck.!?

Comment: Are you sure it's not getting blocked by another session?

Comment: @access_granted yes, it is not blocked.

Comment: @user8271644 I am new to Oracle. What sort of profilers are available?

Comment: Below links mentions some tools for oracle profiling. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148648/oracle-is-there-a-tool-to-trace-queries-like-profiler-for-sql-server

Comment: from the looks of it it might be (the _WAIT_ part). Can you also start checking the v$session_wait ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TKPROF or SQL Profiler. This reports can help you. We can not replay your question now.

If you attach your tuning reports, we can help you. Because many things can cause performance problems. A comprehensive study is needed to understand this.

Follow this link;

[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/perf_overview.htm](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/perf_overview.htm#PFGRF025)

Comment: Is SQL Profiler a specific or general tool?