# How to see the query executed in C# code in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Example: I inserted data to Oracle Query executed successfully but no data is updated in db. So I want to see the same query in Oracle SQL Developer whether its executed or not, how long it took, what data came with insert query.

Comment: @FerasAlSous The issue you mention isn't even related. The OP is interested in whether something similar to `SQL Server Profiler` exists for Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: you can log it manually combining stopwatch and exceptions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148648/oracle-is-there-a-tool-to-trace-queries-like-profiler-for-sql-server

That might have some useful information for you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider enabling SQL trace.

> The quickest way to capture the SQL being processed by a session is to switch on SQL trace or set the 10046 event for a representative period of time. The resulting trace files can be read in their raw state or translated using the tkprof utility.

Some more info with examples [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof)