# ASP.NET identity change tables names for Oracle using Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, identity

To use ASP.NET Identity in Oracle, I have to rename tables names specially schema name. I use the following code to change their names:

[Conext code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC9W5.jpg)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("TRN_ASPNET_USERS", "ADMIN");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("TRN_ASPNET_USERS", "ADMIN");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
            .ToTable("TRN_ASPNET_USER_ROLES", "ADMIN");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
            .ToTable("TRN_ASPNET_USER_LOGINS", "ADMIN");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("TRN_ASPNET_USER_CLAIMS", "ADMIN");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("TRN_ASPNET_ROLES", "ADMIN");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

What I end up with, while I am still using Micorsoft SQL Server. There are newly created tables like the ones I changed their names to. But the old tables names still exist (after recreating the database). And the Identity framework is using the old tables and storing data in the old tables - not in the new tables.

So tables names are changed, but the old tables still exist and are being used. Please help.

[SQL tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0VOZ.jpg)

Comment: did you try to rum something like profiler to know what commands being sent ,,,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148648/oracle-is-there-a-tool-to-trace-queries-like-profiler-for-sql-server

Comment: no i did not, and i am not using oracle yet. i am still trying on ms sql server to successfully rename the tables first then i will move to oracle